# R session aborted after a fatal error in magick_image_readpath

Tags: r, r-markdown, fedora, rmagick

I get the following error with `magick_image_readpath()` when running an example from the R/exams package that relies on this functionality from the R package `magick`. The example is provided in [automaton.Rmd](http://www.R-exams.org/assets/posts/2018-05-13-automaton//automaton.Rmd). I am running this on Fedora 33 in RStudio 1.4.1106 after installing ImageMagick on the system with `sudo yum install ImageMagick-c++-`.

```
## Error in magick_image_readpath(path, density, depth, strip, defines): rsession: Postscript delegate failed `[ghostscript library 95.33] -sstdout=%stderr -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 '-sDEVICE=pngalpha' -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 '-r350x350'  '-sOutputFile=/tmp/Rtmp1RiUH9/magick-0dK6OC7xVxgYfRKmscP07nSEMUTBywn8%d' '-f/tmp/Rtmp1RiUH9/magick-HbbnhIVKvwLM6Lalp02JJd3YUnBal9Kz' '-f/tmp/Rtmp1RiUH9/magick-6mxYCzFKl5e0OhEodSUlNcnKBJPXFWes'': Unrecoverable error: 2 in typecheck
## Operand stack:
##     --nostringval--  rangecheck
## 
## Unexpected interpreter error -1.
## Error object: (a00)int 2
## Operand stack at 0x5644d85cd418:
## 0x5644d85f9068: 0x02 dict --Lwrx--- 0x001d 0x5644d87acaa0
## 0x5644d85f9078: 0x0e name --S------ 0x01fe 0x5644d87f19c8 = rangecheck
## Execution stack at 0x5644d85cd3b0:
## 0x5644d85fc338: 0x10 oper --F---e-- 0x0000 0x7fa6f1130e60 = %interp_exit
## 0x5644d85fc348: 0x03 file --G-rxe-- 0x0001 0x5644d8812958
## 0x5644d85fc358: 0x05 mpry --G--xe-- 0x003f 0x5644d8f0ab1a
## Dictionary stack at 0x5644d85cd318:
## 0x5644d860fc78: 0x02 dict --Gwrx--- 0x0000 0x5644d8701cb8
## 0x5644d860fc88: 0x02 dict --Gwrx--- 0x0000 0x5644d8701cb8
## 0x5644d860fc98: 0x02 dict --Lwrx--- 0x5644 0x5644d85cf2e8
## 0x5644d860fca8: 0x02 dict --Gwrx--- 0x0000 0x5644d8701cb8
##   ./base/gsicc_manage.c:1269: gsicc_open_search(): Could not find default_gray.icc 
## | ./base/gsicc_manage.c:2054: gsicc_set_device_profile(): cannot find device profile
##  @ error/ghostscript-private.h/InvokeGhostscriptDelegate/171
```

Comment: I don't think that this solves the problem but just to make sure: Could you check that you have also the header files installed? I.e. run `sudo yum install  ImageMagick-c++-devel ` and afterwards run `install.packages("magick")` in R again to make sure that the package is compiled against the right ImageMagick version.

Comment: Despite applying those steps, I still have problems with some exercises based on `TikZ` and `include_tikz`.

Comment: OK, thanks for checking. Googling the actual error message suggests that it might be related to a broken iccprofiles configuration in ghostscript. Maybe the solution posted in the following Q&A helps: https://askubuntu.com/questions/924915/broken-ghostscript-configuration